# Add tests to java classpath vscode

Tags: java, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

This is my current setup:

```
├── src
│   ├── mains
│   │   ├── MainP1.java
│   │   └── MainP2.java
│   └── model
│       ├── Board.java
│       ├── CellStatus.java
│       ├── Coordinate.java
│       ├── exceptions
│       │   ├── BattleshipException.java
│       │   ├── CoordinateAlreadyHitException.java
│       │   ├── InvalidCoordinateException.java
│       │   ├── NextToAnotherCraftException.java
│       │   └── OccupiedCoordinateException.java
│       ├── Orientation.java
│       └── Ship.java
└── test
    └── model
        ├── BoardTest.java
        ├── CoordinateTestP1.java
        ├── CoordinateTestP2.java
        └── ShipTest.java
```

**I want to be able to run the tests**, but VSCode doesn't detect them:

[image: vscode capture]

I have tried creating the following .classpath, but still doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
</classpath>
```

I can run the test in the terminal using:

```
JFILE="Coordinate.java"; JTEST="CoordinateTestP1.java"; JCLASS="CoordinateTestP1"; \
javac -cp ./src/ ./src/model/${JFILE} && \
javac -cp ../herramientas/junit-4.13.1.jar:../herramientas/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:./src/:./test/ ./test/model/${JTEST} && \
java -cp ../herramientas/junit-4.13.1.jar:../herramientas/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:./src/:./test/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore model.${JCLASS}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

There is another more convenient approach: You can configure the classpath of your project if it is a project without build tool support (aka unmanaged folder) by triggering the command `Java: Configure Classpath`.

---

You can try right click the folder `test` and select `Add Folder to Java Source Path`

[image]